# How to determine the specific object using another class object as a ManyToMany in a django model?

Tags: django, django-models, relationship

How can I determine the object using another object as seen below?

```
for author in book.authors.all():
    author.some_func(book)
```

It is redundant to input the book as an argument given how we are using it. Is there a way of inherently determining the book? Similar to how we use "self"? In the pseudo code below for the some_func() method, what code would be used for "if called as field from Book object" and "use_this_book = calling Book object"

```
class Book(models.Model):
    authors = ManyToMany(Author, settings)

class Author(models.Model):

    fields = relationships

    def some_func(self, book):
        author = self
        if called as field from Book object:  #  replace this line
            use_this_book = calling Book object  # and this line
        else:
            use_this_book = book
        return do_something_func(author, use_this_book)
```

Comment: This question isn't very clear. Why do you think passing book is redundant? A method can't know that it was called on an object that is an attribute of another object; even if that were possible, it wouldn't be Pythonic, where explicitness is a virtue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `ManyToManyField` defining the relationship between Author and Book, you must pass book into `author.some_func`. This is because an author may have multiple books and you need to pick a specific book to perform the operation on.

If you changed the relationship to be:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    author = ForeignKey(Author, settings)
```

You still have the same issue as an author would still be able to write multiple books. You would be able to do what you want if you were to move the method to `Book`:

```
book.some_func()

class Book:
    def some_func(self):
        author = self.author
        # Other stuff
```

Depending on what `some_func` does this may or may not work for you. However, I would advise you to keep the M2M relationship between Book and Author as that's more flexible and matches how the real world works. Even if it works for you current cases, eventually you will run into a situation where you need multiple authors for a single book.

Comment: The author/book senario is just for the example, it seemed to be a common one I found on some tutorials/examples. When using a ForienKey it would be in a true many to one scenario so each "book" would only have one "author".

Comment: You are right about the ForeignKey example and moving the function to the other class. I added that part to the question at the last minute, for some reason I thought it would clarify what I was doing. It just complicated things, i'll remove it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for.